# How to break a video into pieces using android?

Tags: android, video

I want java code to create partition of video of specific size.
e.g. Consider a video of size 20mb and I want peices of 5 mb each. so we get 4 parts.
I have used code below but it only creates .MP4 file it is not creating video file.

```
    public static void divideFile(File f) {
    int partCounter = 1;//I like to name parts from 001, 002, 003, 
    //you can change it to 0 if you want 000, 001,003 

    int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 1024;// 1MB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

    String fileName = f.getName();

    //try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {

        int bytesAmount = 0;
        while ((bytesAmount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            //write each chunk of data into separate file with different number in name
            String filePartName = String.format("%s.%03d", fileName, partCounter++);
            File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), filePartName);
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesAmount);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want each part to be a playable video itself - in this case each part needs the correct metadata headers to allow a player to handle it properly.

Breaking the video up just by bytes will mean that metadata is not present or not correct in any of the chunks.

You can use ffmpeg to do this correctly with the following command (for mp4):

> ffmpeg -I videoPath -ss startTime -t endTime -c copy outputVideoChunk.mp4

There are several ways to use ffmpeg within an Android app but one of the easiest is to use a well supported wrapper library like:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java